# discord.js make a bot delete a given number of messages

Tags: discord.js

I've started creating a discord bot and I've wanted it to start moderating my server. my first command to try was 'mass delete' or 'purge' which deletes the number of messages a user gives.
But I'm pretty new to java and discord.js so I have no idea how to start.

````
        // code here to check if an mod or above
        // code to delete a number of message a user gave
   }```
````

Answer (score 0):

For permissions checking, you could simply check for the message author's roles using:

```
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(moderator role object)) return;
```

Overall, you should be looking at the `bulkDelete()` function that can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete).

Although, since you don't really know how to really develop bots yet from what you're saying, I won't be telling you the answer to your problem straight ahead. I'd highly recommend learning some JavaScript basics (Also, keep in mind Java != JavaScript) as well as Discord.js basics before you jump head straight into what you want to create.

I'd highly recommend [WornOffKeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV4iltEdBs4&list=PLaxxQQak6D_fxb9_-YsmRwxfw5PH9xALe) on YouTube, they're fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Check user permission first using

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You have no permission to access this command")
```

check bot permission using

```
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("This bot have no permission to delete msg!")
```

return a message when user havnt mention a select message

```
if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("no messages have been selected")
```

then as Bqre said using bulkdelete()

```
 try {
            await message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e); //err
        }
```

hope you find it useful!